# How to pass context to the example from an around hook

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I want to use an around hook to run my specs with a temporary directory present and have the temporary directory cleaned up afterward.

```
describe FileManipulatingClass do

  around(:each) do |example|
    Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
      example.run
    end
  end

  subject { described_class.new dir }

  context "given its help file exists" do
    let(:file_path) { File.join dir "help.txt"}
    before(:each) do
      File.open(file_path, 'w') {|io| io.write "some data" }
    end

    its(:help_text) { should eq("some data") }

  end

end
```

This won't work because the "dir" isn't set for the context. How can I do the equivalent of

```
let(:dir) { ... }
```

and provide a value that only becomes available in the around hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to set an instance variable within your `around` hook, as follows:

```
describe FileManipulatingClass do

  around(:each) do |example|
    Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
      @dir = dir
      example.run
    end
  end

  subject { described_class.new @dir }

  context "given its help file exists" do
    let(:file_path) { File.join @dir "help.txt"}
    before(:each) do
      File.open(file_path, 'w') {|io| io.write "some data" }
    end

    its(:help_text) { should eq("some data") }

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That works if you include a let in the same scope as the around block. Which is fine for my purposes. So the above doesn't work but you could easily correct it to work by adding another let(:dir) {@dir} before the subject line.

Comment: I agree you can use the `let` as in your suggested edit (and it would be better style), but I believe the above example works as is. Did you notice I changed the `dir` to `@dir` in the blocks passed to both `subject and `let`?

Comment: I finally got around to testing this. Yes, you're right. You can use the instance variable in other scopes directly.